# Convert Objective C project to Xamarin

Tags: xamarin.ios, xamarin

We have an app written in Objective C. It uses CoreData, RestKit, about 10 viewcontrollers.

We would like to migrate it to Xamarin (so we can target Android and Windows).

I was hoping there was a way to bind the current code to a Xamarin solution and kind of rewrite features step by step within Xamarin (eg: replacing a viewcontroller at a time, and at the end replacing RestKit+CoreData, by SQLite + ServiceStack).

I am aware of the binding to Objective C option that they provide, however, it doesn't look to be the appropriate fit for this (way too complex, probably easier to rewrite the app from scratch).

Is there a way to migrate our current project to Xamarin so we can convert? or do we start from scratch?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Options:

- Migrate full project - no;
- Automatically create binding for libraries, rewrite business-code, UI-code - yes;
- Rewrite from scratch using `.Net`/`Mono` classes - yes.

If code size is relatively small, you should rewrite the whole app. Moreover, thus you could have a chance to separate business-logic from UI code and tools libraries (`RestKit`, `CoreData`). In perspective, that code will be more reliable and cross-platformish.

Comment: Do you mean that the objective C UI code could be bound from Xamarin?

Comment: You can't create a binding for Android, which is what OP asks for

Comment: @StenPetrov: but if we could bind the existent Objective C code and use it, it would enable us to migrate 'step by step', instead of having to rebuild. Still - I am getting convinced that the proper path is to rebuild from scratch.

Comment: @rufo you are on the right path if you're thinking rewriting. the "step-by-step" approach will drag forever and will impose corner-cutting. I've built a couple of bindings and it is *not* a smooth process

Answer (score 2):

This tool can help.  It does Obj-c to C# translation (some manual cleanup required):

[Automagical](http://razum.si/automagical/)

Comment: Is there any open source or Xamarin tool to do this?

Comment: You can create C# *bindings* for Objective-C libraries using Objective Sharpie by Xamarin:
https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/cross-platform/macios/binding/objective-sharpie/

Answer (score 1):

Quite probably, a re-write, from scratch.  One thing to keep in mind, if your back-end is .net.. and you are using DTO's.. like with AutoMapper from Entity Framework objects.. you'll be able to re-use those DTO objects on your mobile side with Xamarin.  If you are using OData, I'm not sure if this is still a problem, but Xamarin studio wasn't generating OData service clients.   So you had to generate them in Visual Studio, then take the generated client code and throw them into your Mobile projects.

sqllite-net is awesome.  I've never had any problems with it.

https://github.com/praeclarum/sqlite-net

I currently have a project, with DTO Objects from an Azure WCF service, that I push directly down into SQLLite objects on IOS and Android with Xamarin.  I use RestSharp, rather than Service Stack.  I should probably go learn the difference.

If you are looking to use SQLCipher from the Component store, to encrypt your sqllite db locally on your device (Good advice to do so), you should be aware that there is an issue in android.. going to 2.2 or 2.3 with SQLCipher.  Works for ICS and above though, if I remember right.

Just be careful on your security implementation for allowing clients to connect.  I want to say.. don't take too much advice.. and don't take too little either. : )